# How do i assign value?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I am  trying to assign a value inside another function, but it is not working, what is the correct way to do this?

```
f = function () {
  var foo = 6;
  function() {
     foo = 4;
  };
  alert(foo);
};
f();
```

Comment: Did you try to execute the program?

Comment: yes, i have tried it, but not working, actually the second function is a ajax callback function

Comment: see this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work] to see closure in action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not calling the function. You need to do something like this:

```
f = function () {
  var foo = 6;
  var func = function() {
     foo = 4;
  };
  func();
  alert(foo);
};
f();
```

---

You indicated in a comment that your function is actually a callback, which is a completely different question. If you do:

```
f = function () {
  var foo = 6;
  somethingAsync(function() {
     foo = 4;
  });
  alert(foo);
};
f();
```

The function will run, but it will run the alert first, and you won't see the updated value. Instead, you should put the alert in the function itself:

```
f = function () {
  var foo = 6;
  somethingAsync(function() {
     foo = 4;
     alert(foo);
  });
};
f();
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but what if the inner function is an ajax callback?

Comment: will the value of foo changes from 6 to 4?

Comment: @sajadkk It will when the callback is called.

Comment: I need to return the new value , is it possible?

Comment: @sajadkk No, that's an important part of how async programming works. Callbacks run *after* the function they're in, not *during*.

Comment: Thanks @Kendall Frey , you were much helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
var f = function () {
  var foo = 6;
  function x() {
     foo = 4;
  };
  alert(foo);
};
f();
```

You never call x, so the value stays the same!

Answer (score -1):

```
var f1;
f1= function() {
     foo = 4;
     alert(foo);
  };
f = function () {
  var foo = 6;
  f1();

};

f();
```

Link :http://plnkr.co/edit/wKDoimqEx1IuTzGPEu8c?p=preview

Comment: yea..I have added the demo

Answer (score -2):

You must initialize the inner function

```
f = function () {
  var foo = 6;
  return function() {
     foo = 4;
     alert(foo);
  };
};
f()();
```

Comment: Are you sure this is how you "initialize" a function?